# How to color some matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

images = []

c=0
a=0
b=0
while a < 31:
    mat0 = np.zeros((100, 100))
    i=0
    while i < 3:
        k = 0
        while k < 3:
            mat0[a+i, a+k+c] = 1+b
            k += 1
        i+=1
    images.append(mat0)
    a+=1
    c+=1
    b+=1

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.matshow(images[2], cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

I'd like to color each non-zero enter of the matrix with a different shade of blue for each matrix.
For example images[0] contains a block of 1 that I want color with a light blue, images[1] contains a block of "2" that I want to color with a darker blue, and so on. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work!

Comment: ok solved setting vmin and vmx, thx @Yacola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, by also setting accordingly `vmin` and `vmax` kwargs:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for image in images:
    ax.cla()
    ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, vmin=1, vmax=31)
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

which gives:

[image: imshow_shades_bluish]